# Что можно сделать с помощью Active Directory в Windows Server 2008?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server

Здравствуйте. Извините, я знаю что надо было тему создавать в РутКод, но там никто мне не отвечает вот уже третий день, и не только на мой вопрос, вот и решил тут написать. Если кто то знает, пусть ответит. Буду весьма благодарен!

Что можно сделать с помощью Active Directory? Перечислите мне просто что можно сделать с его помощью. Только не отвечайте "все!". Т.к я после согласно этому буду изучать это все. Как бы со ставьте мне план, что мне выучить.

Прошу, не удаляйте мой пост. Он реально важен мне. Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 2):

Наверное нужно было адать вопрос по другому - "Для чего нужен Active Directory и какие фцнкции он выполняет?", может тогда на руткоде вам и ответии бы ;)

Если вам нужно разобраться что такое Active Directory, то:

[Основы изучения](https://www.google.ru/search?q=active%20directoy)
[Тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory)
[Тут](http://alexeynayda.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-active-directory/)
[Тут](http://www.globalit.ru/articles/windows/why-company-needs-active-directory.html)

Так же не забывайте про [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com)

Answer (score 0):

К примеру, есть такая служба Active Directory Fedration Service, которая  реализует систему единого входа (Single Sing-On).

Например так:
есть 3 машины:
1. ADFS - хранит данные пользователей.
2. IIS(веб-сервер) - сервер, на котором работает Ваше веб-приложение.
3. Client - пользователь, который использует веб-приложение.

Пользователь заходит на Ваше веь-приложение и ему нужно авторизоваться, но у него нет учетной записи на Вашем веб-приложении. Но зато у него есть учётная запись в Active Directory.  Он может воспользоваться ею, чтобы не создавать заново учётную запись в веб-приложении.

Можете прочитать про протокол SAML, который служит для этой цели.

По такому принципу работает авторизация на многих сайтах. Например, авторизоваться на stackoverflow при помощи учётной записи google.